# Doctrine2 entity , tell not update certain columns

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I don't want to update certain columns for the table.

In the Questions table, I just want to update the question column:

```
question:

id
question
created_by
created_at
modified_by
modified_at
is_Active
```

In the above table column, I don't need to update the `create_at`, `created_by`, `modified_by`, `modified_at`, is_active columns. This is the entity I am using.

**Entity:**

```
    <?php

    namespace Library\Entity;

    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

    /**
     * Base class for all the Entities
     * This class maps id, active, created and modified columns 
     *
     * @author 

 */
/**
 * @ORM\MappedSuperclass
 */
class BaseEntity {

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @var integer
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="is_active", type="boolean")
     * @var boolean
     */
    protected $active;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="created_at", type="datetime")
     * @var datetime
     */
    protected $createdAt;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="created_by", type="integer", nullable=true)
     * @var integer
     */
    protected $createdBy;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="modified_at", type="datetime")
     * @var datetime
     */
    protected $modifiedAt;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="modified_by", type="integer")
     * @var integer
     */
    protected $modifiedBy;

    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getActive() {
        return $this->active;
    }

    public function getCreatedAt() {
        return $this->createdAt;
    }

    public function getCreatedBy() {
        return $this->createdBy;
    }

    public function getModifiedAt() {
        return $this->modifiedAt;
    }

    public function getModifiedBy() {
        return $this->modifiedBy;
    }

    public function setId($id) {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    public function setActive($active) {
        $this->active = $active;
    }

    public function setCreatedAt($createdAt) {
        $this->createdAt = $createdAt;
    }

    public function setCreatedBy($createdBy) {
        $this->createdBy = $createdBy;
    }

    public function setModifiedAt($modifiedAt) {
        $this->modifiedAt = $modifiedAt;
    }

    public function setModifiedBy($modifiedBy) {
        $this->modifiedBy = $modifiedBy;
    }
}
```

**This is my `Question` Entity:**

```
<?php

namespace Survey\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Library\Entity\BaseEntity;
use Survey\Entity\Survey;

/**
 * Description of Survey Questions
 *
 * @author Mubarak
 */

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="survey_questions")
 */

class Question extends BaseEntity{

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="question", type="string")
     * @var string
     */
    protected $question;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Survey\Entity\Survey", inversedBy="questions")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="survey_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $surveys;

    public function getQuestion() {
        return $this->question;
    }

    public function setQuestion($question) {
        $this->question = $question;
    }

    public function getSurveys() {
        return $this->surveys;
    }

//    public function setSurveys(ArrayCollection $survey) {
    public function setSurveys(Survey $surveys = null) {
        $this->surveys = $surveys;
    }

//    public function __toString() {
//        return __CLASS__ . ": [id: {$this->id}, name: {$this->name}]";
//    }
}
```

Here is my update function:

```
public function updateQuestion($userId, $data ) {
        try{
            $surveyId = 1;
            $survey = $this->entityManager->getRepository('Survey\Entity\Survey')->find($surveyId);
            $question = new Question();
            $question->setQuestion($data['question']);
            $question->setSurveys($survey);
            $question->setId(1);
            $this->entityManager->merge($question);
            $this->entityManager->flush();
        } catch (Exception $ex) {
            throw new Exception("Couldnt update the Question");
        }
```

Below is my error message i am getting:

> An exception occurred while executing 'UPDATE survey_questions SET is_active = ?, created_at = ?, created_by = ?, modified_at = ?, modified_by = ? WHERE id = ?' with params [null, null, null, null, null, 1]:\n\nSQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'created_at' cannot be null

Here is my insert Operation:

```
public function insertQuestion($userId, $survey, $questionArr) {
        try{
            $question = new Question();
            $question->setQuestion($questionArr['question']);
            $question->setSurveys($survey);
            $question->setActive(1);
            $question->setCreatedBy($userId);
            $question->setCreatedAt($this->createdAt);
            $question->setModifiedBy($userId);
            $question->setModifiedAt($this->modifiedAt);
            $this->entityManager->persist($question);
            $this->entityManager->flush();
            return $question;
        }catch(Exception $ex){
           throw new Exception("Couldnt insert the question");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are creating a new entity, `Question`.

> When calling `EntityManager::flush()` Doctrine computes the changesets of all the currently managed entities and saves the differences to the database. In case of object properties (`@Column(type=”datetime”)` or `@Column(type=”object”)`) these comparisons are always made *BY REFERENCE*.

"By reference" is important because your new entity has `null` values for all date time fields (rather than the previously set `\DateTime` instances). When `flush()` is called Doctrine correctly detects that these fields are changed and performs the query which fails at the *database* level.

The `merge()` operation isn't required in Doctrine when 'editing' entities, these are used for *detached* instances that need to be managed again.

To solve this you should load the managed instance of the entity first; then modify the fields and flush.

```
$question = $entityManager->find(1);
$question->setQuestion($data['question']);
$entityManager->flush();
```

Comment: Hi Alex, its worked magnificently, your words are clear and precise, you saved me lots of time, also i have one another clarification,  i have updated the insert operation, how can i tell that, created_at(current timestamp), is_active(default 1) set in the mysql db structure needs to be taken. When in omit the $question->setCreatedAt($this->createdAt); in the above insert operation its shows me the similiar integrity constraint violation, do you know what is the issue?